# How to add onkeypress event to dynamically created input box in IE?

Tags: javascript, html

All, 
  I am adding input box on onclick function as below

```
   HtmlContent =HtmlContent+  "<input id = '" + uid + "' onkeypress='DefaultEnterButton(event,&apos;imgGo&apos;)' class='jobCenterArea' type='text'   onkeydown='IsNumeric(" + uid + ")'  onclick ='getActiveElementId();' name='txtBoxSch_" + txtBoxCnt + "' />&nbsp;" +
            "<img src='/COSimages/BusPortal/custom-x.png'  alt='Close Icon' height='14' width ='14' onclick=' Remove_TextBox(" + uid + ")'/>&nbsp;"+htmllabel;
```

The above code is working fine in FF, chrome and safari but not in IE[7 & 8]

I tried below code ,but not working in IE

```
document.getElementById(uid).onkeypress = function(event){return DefaultEnterButton(event,'imgGo')};
```

[The functionality i am trying to achieve is ,after the user enter the keyword,when they hit enter button ,it should go to next page not only just by clicking search button ]
Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
The solution is replacing `&apos;` by `&#39;` .

http://www.digimantra.com/tips/how-to-display-apos-in-internet-explorer-ie/

Thanks everybody for the input.

Comment: Look into jQuery. It really simplifies DOM manipulation and event handling (and AJAX and ...), especially when IE8 needs to be supported.

Comment: It's much cleaner and easier to hook up the event handlers dynamically as well, especially when using jQuery.

Comment: And if you're producing a lot of such "dynamic" content, look into a client-side template engine, such as [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: @voithos jQuery has its own templating system as well ;-)

Comment: what are `HtmlContent` and `DefaultEnterButton`? They're not provided by the browser nor is the former a good name for a "mere" text variable.

Comment: \' is throwing syntax error in FF

Comment: HtmlContent  is local variable and DefaultEnterButton is the event i am calling onkeypress

Comment: In ie<9 event objects aren't sent to element.on* event handlers. use `function(event){return DefaultEnterButton(event || window.event,'imgGo')};`